# SQL Server Substring variable length - numerals of varying length with no consistent pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, sql-server-2017

I've checked the many threads here related to variable-length Substrings - none have answered my specific case - please don't mark as possible duplicate unless I somehow missed it.

Azure SQL Server 2017

I have a `varchar(50)` field called `Name` in a table `dbo.MyTable` with these kinds of values:

```
1143_RRF-tansTracks
DGGP-45-HAEJTJ_wer
3TTKH_YPreTTR
4534554PostRTE
WERET677ITD
PINT_pilly-er_45321
```

I am attempting to use `SUBSTRING` to  get this:

```
1143
45
3
4534554
677
45321
```

I am having trouble understanding how to define the `length` parameter.

What I have so far:

```
SUBSTRING(Name, (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',[Name])),7) AS Number
```

The `7` is just there as a placeholder - how would I properly write the `length` parameter to achieve my number extraction?

Comment: Do you want to get all the numbers inside a string? i.e. abc123def456 returns 123456? Or should that return 123? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so nice, but if you really need a one-liner:

```
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Name, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Name),999),1,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',SUBSTRING(Name,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Name),999)+'x')-1)
```

Or:

```
SUBSTRING(Name,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Name),LEN(NAME)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REVERSE(Name))-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Name)+2)
```

Comment: While it may not be the prettiest or most efficient, I am going with this one as it works with SQL built-in functionality and doesn't require me to create my own function.  The other answers are all really good and I'm sure this whole thread will be of benefit to others.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `TRANSLATE()` and `REPLACE()` function as

```
SELECT Str,
       REPLACE(
       TRANSLATE(Str, 'abcdefghiJklmnopqrstuvwxyz_-',
                      '                            '), ' ', '')
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('1143_RRF-tansTracks'),
  ('DGGP-45-HAEJTJ_wer'),
  ('3TTKH_YPreTTR'),
  ('4534554PostRTE'),
  ('WERET677ITD'),
  ('PINT_pilly-er_45321')
) T(Str);
```

<kbd>**[`Online Demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fdc8f6e9b365216c0fcbeea1a6b16586)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like this to get number from the string in SQL Server as shown below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric (@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intAlpha INT

    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)

    BEGIN
        WHILE @intAlpha > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '')
            SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
        END
    END

    RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric, 0)
END
GO

SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('1143_RRF-tansTracks') AS NumberFromString;
```

Here is the [demo](https://rextester.com/FSXJXJ45445) given.

Comment: I would avoid using a scalar function for this. An inline table valued function using a tally table would make this quite a bit faster.

Comment: Yes, for table column it can be converted into table valued function after doing some changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to using a scalar function. This will outperform a scalar function by leaps and bounds.

```
create function [dbo].[GetNumbersOnly](@pString varchar(8000))
returns table as return
    WITH
        E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
        E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
        E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
        cteTally(N) AS (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4)
    , ValueList as 
    (
        SELECT N, SUBSTRING(@pString, N, 1) as NewVal
        FROM cteTally
        WHERE N <= LEN(@pString)
            AND SUBSTRING(@pString, N, 1) LIKE ('[0-9]')  
    )

    SELECT top 1 NewVal = replace(STUFF((
                   SELECT '+' + NewVal
                     FROM ValueList
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,''), '+', '')
    FROM ValueList
```

And then you could leverage this for your current output.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Name varchar(100)
)

insert @Something values
('1143_RRF-tansTracks')
, ('DGGP-45-HAEJTJ_wer')
, ('3TTKH_YPreTTR')
, ('4534554PostRTE')
, ('WERET677ITD')
, ('PINT_pilly-er_45321')

select *
from @Something s
cross apply dbo.GetOnlyNumbers(s.Name) n
```